# Create a bijection $g:\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\to(0,1)$ and justify why $g$ is a bijection

Tags: functions

> Create a bijection $g:\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\to(0,1)$. Then justify why $g$ is a bijection.

I believe that you can use the function $\sin(x)$ as the bijection, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: What do you know about bijections? You can even find a simpler one: the linear function which send $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to $(0,1)$.

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{x}{\pi} + \frac12$ might be easier to prove than $\sin(x)$.

Comment: $\sin x$ is a good starting point, but $\sin x$ maps from $(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2) \to (-1,1)$  So, you need to tweak it slightly.  Nonetheless, what is a bijection?  Tell us the definition.  (It is both an injection and a surjection, now what are those)  Then what characteristics do you need to work into your function?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something linear: $y(x)=mx+q$. Then it will be easy to show that it is a bijection by finding the inverse map $x(y)=(y-q)/m$.

Now let $y(-\pi/2)=0$ and $y(\pi/2)=1$ and find $m$ and $q$.